# Understanding Scala implicit conversion and generic type inference

Tags: scala

```
trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits {
  implicit def ordered[A <: Ordered[A]]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
    def compare(x: A, y: A) = x.compare(y)
  }
}
```

What does the above code do?

1. What does A <: Ordered[A] mean? How can A be a subtype of Ordered[A]?
2. What exactly does "new Ordering[A]{..." do? Does it create a new anonymous class for Ordering[A]?

Also, for this code (taken from the [DataStax Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala))

```
        object TableWriter{
          def apply[T : RowWriterFactory](
          connector: CassandraConnector,
          keyspaceName: String,
          tableName: String,
          columnNames: ColumnSelector,
          writeConf: WriteConf): TableWriter[T] = {
            ...//some code
            val rowWriter = implicitly[RowWriterFactory[T]].rowWriter(tableDef, selectedColumns)
            new TableWriter[T](connector, tableDef, rowWriter, writeConf)
          }
        }
        val writer = TableWriter(connector, keyspaceName, tableName, columns, writeConf) // first call

        def saveToCassandra(keyspaceName: String,
                          tableName: String,
                          columns: ColumnSelector = AllColumns,
                          writeConf: WriteConf = WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sparkContext.getConf))
                         (implicit connector: CassandraConnector = CassandraConnector(sparkContext.getConf),
                          rwf: RowWriterFactory[T]): Unit = {
             val writer = TableWriter(connector, keyspaceName, tableName, columns, writeConf)// 2nd call
        }
```

1. How does the type of T get inferred?
2. What's the purpose of rwf implicit param?
3. What's the difference between the first and second calls to TableWriter?

Answer (score 0):

> What does A <: Ordered[A] mean? How can A be a subtype of Ordered[A]?

Let's look at the definition of `Ordered`:

```
trait Ordered[A] extends Any with java.lang.Comparable[A] {

  def compare(that: A): Int

  /* ... */
}
```

If we say that `A <: Ordered[A]`, then we specify that instances of `A` are comparable to other instances of `A`. Why is this necessary in the given case? Well... say we have

```
implicit def ordered[B, A <: Ordered[B]]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
  def compare(x: A, y: A) = x.compare(y)
}
```

This code won't compile, because `Ordered[B]` has no method `compare(x: A)` (note that `y` is of type `A`).

> What exactly does "new Ordering[A]{..." do? Does it create a new anonymous class for Ordering[A]?

Yes, this is an anonymous class.

> How does the type of T get inferred?

`T: RowWriterFactory` is a context-bound. See also the [Scala doc about type tags and manifests](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

As far as I know,

```
def foo[T: RowWriterFactory](x: Int)
```

is the same as writing

```
def foo[T](x: Int)(implicit evidence: RowWriterFactory[T])
```

> What's the purpose of rwf implicit param?

This follows from the answer to the previous question: It's the context bound. Though I do not know the usage in this particular example. **Edit** As the `apply`-method of `TableWriter` requires the `RowWriterFactory` through the context bound, the purpose of `rfw` is to be used as implicit parameter to `TableWriter.apply`.

> What's the difference between the first and second calls to TableWriter?

Without knowing the arguments to the first call, they are identical, aren't they?

Comment: 1) What does A <: Ordered[A] mean? I still don't get it.... how is A a subtype of Ordered[A] if it doesn't inherit from it? (I'm new to scala, so this might be a stupid question)

Comment: 2) I still don't get how T gets inferred? Like how does the compiler know what implicit conversion to perform? What is the parameterised type of rwf?

Comment: 3) The purpose of rwf.... What stops saveToCassandra from calling TableWriter.apply without the context bound? (just like I did in the first TableWriter call). When I'm testing the code, I get different  results  for the two TableWriter call - I think that's because the context bound  gets resolved differently. Not sure why

Comment: The code is from :https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala

Comment: the implicitly call in apply(...) demands an implicit RowWriterFactory. So if you didn't have the factory implicitly passed to saveToCassandra you would get an error

Comment: I just remembered this great article. Maybe it helps in understanding the issues: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Comment: @elmalto this is a very good read, thank you. Feel free to update the answer (or provide your own). If not, I'll update the answer myself if I find the time.